# JSON schema validation POST vs. GET

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Is there a way to define a JSON schema to require certain fields based on the HTTP method? Pseudocode would look something like:

```
IF Http POST
   Require [field1, field2, field3]
IF Http GET
   Require [fieldX, fieldY, fieldZ]
```

Comment: JSON Schema is not linked to an HTTP request. JSON Schema can, and often is, done without any context to an HTTP request. What are you trying to do and in what situation?

Comment: We are using the same schema to validate an incoming HTTP request (POST) as we are for an outgoing HTTP request (GET). For an incoming request we take the JSON, parse it out, and populate our database. For the outgoing request we do the opposite, query the database and respond with a JSON payload. The JSON schema is almost the same for both, with some slight additions to the outgoing request. I would love to adjust the schema based on the outgoing vs. incoming requests

Comment: OK so you create two schemas. JSON Schema libraries take two inputs, the schema and the instance. They have no knowledge of where they are being used. They are often used offline or just in the browser. I repeat, JSON Schema itself does not know where it is being used, nor about an HTTP request. What leads you to think that JSON Schema has this sort of knowledge?

Comment: I didn't necessarily think that the schema is self aware of the HTTP method, but I was just checking to see if there was any way to manipulate the schema to accomplish my task. I am trying to avoid managing 2 separate schemas if possible

Comment: OK. Well JSON Schema IS also just JSON, so you would manipulate it in the same way you would for normal JSON. Additionally, if it's always going to be the same for a build, you might want to make a modified copy of your schema at build time rather than run time on each request.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate your insight. But it sounds like there really is not way to inject logic into the schema based on the HTTP method, since the JSON schema has no way to understand that

Comment: No. Sorry. Always feel free to post more JSON Schema questions!